# nXML mode for web development

Tags: emacs, nxml

Is it possible to make nXML mode more convenient for web development?
Specifically:

1. Treat `<? ... ?>` bits as if they didn't exist
2. Don't issue "Unknown element" warnings when the XML schema is
   unknown

I'd rather not use a multi-mode

#### Edit:

Regarding point 2, the vacuous schema is supposed to do that, but it gets confused when there is no root element. A quick fix is to wrap everything in a tag with any name

#### Edit2:

A better fix still, might be to write a script that will:

- Check if the schema is vacuous, after entering nxml mode
- If it is, add `<temporary-root-tag>` in the beginning of the document
- Before saving, remove the tag
- After saving, put the tag back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `(rng-validate-mode 0)` is probably a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about [nxhtml mode](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html)? It is specifically for web development and it builds on nxml.

Comment: I've tried using it, but it left me an impression of being unstable.